# checkbox not changing value

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

The following will not change the value of the checkbox to true or false, it seems to be stuck on true.

So even if a user does not want to agree to the terms it is making it look like the user has not unclicked the checkbox (yes the checkbox does remove the tick tho)

I am wondering what do I need to change in the following to get it to update the const.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    marriedstatus: '',
    employmentstatus: '',
    dependants: '',
    income:'',
    firsthomebuyer:'',
    interest:'',
    whentobuild:'',
    firstname: '',
    lastname:'',
    email:'',
    mobile:'',
    state:'',
    suburb:'',
    country:'',
    besttimetocall:'',
    agree: false,
  });




const handleChange = name => event => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };


 <Grid item lg={6} xs={12}> 
            <Controller as={<FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth="true">
            <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="agree">
            Agree
            </InputLabel><Checkbox
        name="agree"
        value={state.agree}
        checked={true} 
        onChange={handleChange('agree')}
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'agree' }}
/></FormControl>} name="Agree" control={control} />
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `checked={true}` hardcoded for your checkbox.